# SP2010 Delete a site through code

Tags: 2010, development

I'm using the following code to let users without full access rights on my site deleting it through a custom layouts page (delete site button):

```
  SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() {
         using (SPSite Site = SPContext.Current.Site) {
                 Site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                 Site.Delete();
                 Site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
         }
        });
```

I get an access denied for the non site collection user trying to do this:

Deleting the site at http:// and not deleting AD accounts.
Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070005
An SPRequest object was not disposed before the end of this thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing a reference of the existing SPSite which also passes the current security context. Instead try:

```
  SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() {
         using (SPSite Site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID)) {
                 Site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                 Site.Delete();
                 Site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
         }
        });
```